# How can I change how this code is being handled in a try catch block?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

So I have this HTML form that takes user input and sends it to a Google Sheet. This is done through the following JavaScript code:

```js
const sheetName = 'Sheet1'
const scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

function initialSetup () {
  const activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
}

function doPost (e) {
  const lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try {
    const doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    const sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    const headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    const nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

    const newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'Date' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}
```

When the user submits the form, there are taken to a new link that shows the following:

[image: Correct User submission]

If there is an error, they are also taken to a new link with a similar message, that shows this:

`{ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }`

How can I change the contents of a code to simply show a JavaScrip alert like:
`alert('Data has been sent!')` or `alert('Oops. An error occurred...')`.

I am assuming this would take place in:

```js
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
```

And:

```js
  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }
```

HTML Form:

```html
    <form 
  method="POST" 
  action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby_xq-vLOZD0cXzN0vvvNYG40GK5yde0HYQD9IUq3FGGTcDggk3kG9QkmtBFSg037Le/exec"
>
  <input name="Job" type="text" placeholder="Job" required>
  <input name="Name" type="text" placeholder="Name" required>
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Sample alert:

[image: Sample Alert]

Apologies if the wording of the question is off.

Comment: About `How can I change the contents of a code to simply show a JavaScrip alert like: alert('Data has been sent!') or alert('Oops. An error occurred...').`, if you want to open a dialog by `alert('Data has been sent!')`, it is required to know your HTML and Javascript side. If my understanding is correct, can you provide it?

Comment: @Tanaike i have edited my post with a short HTML Form.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About your HTML, where is this HTML? If the HTML is included in the container-bound script of Google Apps Script, a dialog of Spreadsheet can be used. But if your HTML is put out of Google Apps Script, a simple alert can be used. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike the HTML form is located in a separate Visual Studio Code file. The JavaScript code in my post is located in the Apps Script online editor.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your current situation and your goal are as follows.

- From your reply of `the HTML form is located in a separate Visual Studio Code file. The JavaScript code in my post is located in the Apps Script online editor.`, I understood that your HTML is put out of Google Apps Script project.
- You want to submit the values from the HTML form to your Web Apps.
- After the values were sent to Web Apps, you want to open an alert on the client side.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, your HTML is modified as follows. Before you use this script, please set your Web Apps URL to `url`. In this case, your Google Apps Script is not required to be modified.

```
<form>
  <input name="Job" type="text" placeholder="Job" required>
  <input name="Name" type="text" placeholder="Name" required>
  <button type="submit" onclick="sample(this);return false;">Send</button>
</form>

<script>
  function sample(e) {

    const url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec"; // Please set your Web Apps URL.

    const obj = [...e.parentNode].reduce((o, f) => (o[f.name] = f.value, o), {});
    const query = new URLSearchParams(obj); 
    fetch(url + "?" + query, { method: "POST" })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        alert(res.result);
      });
  }
</script>
```

- In this modification, when the form is submitted, the values are sent to Web Apps using `fetch`. And, after the values were sent, the returned value is retrieved and an alert is opened.

#### Note:

- Although in your question, the setting of Web Apps is not included, from your HTML, I guessed that the setting of Web Apps is `Execute as: Me` and `Who has access to the app: Anyone` (using new IDE). Please be careful about this.
- This modified scrupt supposes that your Google Apps Script works fine. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [Using the Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Answer (score 0):

```
let text = "Type what you want";
return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"message":text}));
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
```

Comment: I am not quite sure this would work because it would send a JSON text output. The alert would look more like the one I have just added to the post.